# How to create an extension command with Python for SPSS?

Tags: python, xml, spss

I'm trying to create an extension command with Python for SPSS, but this is throwing me an error that I don't understand:

```
Warnings
This command should specify a valid subcommand at the beginning.
Execution of this command stops.
```

Here is my xml:

```xml
<Command
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/extension-1.0.xsd"
Name="xxxRENAME TEST" Language="Python">
<Subcommand Name="OPTIONS" Occurrence="Optional" EqualsSign="None">
    <Parameter Name="TEST" EqualsSign="Required" ParameterType="Keyword">
        <EnumValue Name="A"/>
        <EnumValue Name="B"/>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="TEST1" EqualsSign="Required" ParameterType="Keyword">
        <EnumValue Name="C"/>
        <EnumValue Name="D"/>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="TEST2" EqualsSign="Required" ParameterType="Keyword">
        <EnumValue Name="E"/>
        <EnumValue Name="F"/>
    </Parameter>
</Subcommand>
</Command>
```

And my .py `Run` looks like that:

```py
def Run (args):
    args=args[args.keys()[0]]
    oobj = Syntax([
        Template("TEST",subc="OPTIONS",ktype="str",var="test",vallist=["a","b"]),
        Template("TEST1",subc="OPTIONS",ktype="str",var="test1",vallist=["c","d"]),
        Template("TEST2",subc="OPTIONS",ktype="str",var="test2",vallist=["e","f"])
        ])
    processcmd(oobj,args,Renaming)
```

My `renaming` function in python was tested and works fine, so I guess the issue is in the XML or `Run` function?
What is confusing me more is that I have an extension command with TEST and TEST1 which is working fine. If anyone has any clue...

Comment: What are names of your files and are they under extensions folder in SPSS folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the name of the extension was conflicting with another one. So it was fixed by renaming it differently.